# Performance discrepency between nested and direct querying (execution plan states optimisation false?)

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, hasura

In my Hasura query if I do the following query as a user with permissions:

```
{
    feed {
        feed_items {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

The response time is in the mid 2 seconds, however if I just do:

```
{
  feed_item {
    id
  }
}
```

The response time is typically under half a second.

Feed is a simple table object with a primary key while feed_item is a table with quite complex auth requirements with a foreign key pointing at the feed it belongs to.

If the permissions are set to Admin (i.e. no permissions) performance is very fast on both queries, but with permissions the second query is slower - I would have thought as feed_item has all the complex permissions that should be the slow one and querying through feed would have neglible impact on performance.

Looking at the execution plan, the slow execution has a result of 'optimisation false' while the fast one is 'optimisation true' - I feel like I need to create an index or something between the feed/feed item relationship to speed up the query? Makes very little sense otherwise.

For the query directly to feed this is the analysis/generated sql I get back from hasura: https://pastebin.com/EgF05R0c

For the query via feed I get: https://pastebin.com/KEmV2A3b

For minimal possible variation there is no data in the database, everything returned is empty arrays.

Comment: In general if you're accessing things primarily based on a foreign key relationship its going to be helpful to have an index there. I would definitely start by adding that and re-running the query analysis to see if it makes a difference.


For reference this is a tool I sometimes use for visualizing query plans that can be super helpful. I've run your second query plan through it here: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/S69#plan